Selenium WebDriverWait try/finally statement fails even if expected condition is met
I'm following the documentation on the Selenium website for how to wait for Ajax responses before proceeding, and while the correct dynamically loaded information is found, a timeout error is still thrown.
What my code should do is load a website, wait until dynamically populated elements of a specific class appears, and get the attribute of the classes.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'path\to\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
driver.get('https://website')

result="placeholder"

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "class name"))
    )
finally:
    html_input = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_input, features="html.parser")
    for each_item in soup.findAll(class_='class name'):
        result = each_item['href']
        print(result)
    driver.quit()

My output is
*The output I was looking for*

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 47, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\CondaEnv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

The print statements are executing, but I'm still getting a timeout error. I'm not sure how to proceed without putting all the other code I want in the finally part.

while the correct dynamically loaded information is found, a timeout error is still thrown I don't see how these can both be true.  If the element was found it shouldn't throw a timeout, and if it throws a timeout then the element wasn't found.  Please show us the exact code and output which makes you think both conditions are happening.

Edited the question to include the exact code and output. Thanks!

The traceback shows WebDriverWait(driver, 3) but the posted code has WebDriverWait(driver, 10).  So that error is not coming from this code.

Sorry, forgot about that. Changed the code wait time back to 10 and got the same error, but with 10.

you are not catching the exception... finally will always run... but your wait only waits for a single element... while in your finally block you are telling  soup to find all elements with that class name.  What leads to the error, though is that a space separates two different CSS classes.  So By.CLASS_NAME will fail here as it tries to find a single class with a space.  Using XPATH to search for attribute of class="class name" would work, though you've only waited for the presence of one element with this attribute.

This is a timeout exception, which means the element you are referencing using the class name is not found.

The issue is I am getting the element, the code in the finally statement is executing, yet it's still throwing the error.

This doesn't seem to answer the whole question. Explaining the error is great, but this answer would be better if it also explained why the error is occurring and/or how it can be fixed.

The code in the finally statement is executing because it is meant to execute in any case. Even when it fails to get the element, the finally statement will still execute. While use try/except, finally is the default for anything that you want to execute even when the rest of the code fails.
To fix this, keep the try as is, add except TimeOutException: print("Element not found") before the finally. This way, you will know if it found the element or not.
For more clarity: Check this: try/except/finally

Interesting, for some reason if I change finally to except while leaving the rest of the code untouched, it works.

Cool.
That solves the problem.
